# Is there a way to stream data as well as read the data that is already in MongoDB through apache-spark

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I just started using scala-spark. I want to read the data from MongoDB as well as the streaming data which will be sent to MongoDB. I know there are different functions to read data from MongoDB like "spark.read.mongo" and a separate function to stream data using "spark.readStream". But I want to know is there a way in which I do both of them simultaneously.

PS: I tried searching for the same in stack overflow but couldn't find any. If there is already a similar question please direct me to the same.

Comment: So you want to read and store data to mongo at same time via spark?

Comment: Have you looked at something like this,

https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/scala/streaming/

Comment: @Sohan actually the thing is I am writing data into mongo through nifi flows and also there will be some data previously in the mongo which doesnt come from nifi. So I want to 
1. read the previously written data and
2. and the data that will streamed to mongo through nifi
both 1& 2 at a time

Comment: Ohh... Not sure if mongo spark has got something like that. You need to have your own logic around for this i think so. This is more to your requirement specific.

Comment: Oh.. Thanks anyway,